# li won't float correctly in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-float

I have a very peculiar problem across the IE board (ignoring IE6).

Basically I have a list in a div with fixed width. The list contains li cells without height or width, containing a link and a styled span tag. The li cells are supposed to float right, with the span tag floating right relative to the `<a>`

Problem, IE can't handle it. And I absolutely don't know where to begin.

```
div#all { 
    width: 800px; 
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    }

div#head { 
    width: 800px; 
    margin: 0;
    }

ul { 
    width: 800px; 
    list-style: none; 
    margin: 35px 0 10px 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    }

ul span {
    float: right;
    display: block; 
    height: 18px; 
    width: 18px; 
    margin: 0 0 0 6px; 
    }

li  { 
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 15px;
    padding: 0 0 4px 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    }

li a {
    float: left;
    }

  <ul>
      <li class="ABC">
      <a href="ABCD">ABCD</a>
      <span class="li-ABC">
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Ignore the span class and the li class, they just have color settings

Site can be viewed [here](http://news-hoff.appspot.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have HTML errors. There are several list items in a row that do this:

```
                <li class="ArabicWorld">
                <a class="menu" href="/Arabic World/Arabic World">
                    العالم العربي
                </a>
                <span class="li-ArabicWorld">
                </li>
```

Note the unclosed `<span>`. You open a new span for each list item but don't close it. There may be other issues as well. Always [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) before blaming the browser. The reason it looks OK in other browsers is most likely because they were handling the error differently.

Comment: Yep, that was it. The unclosed span pretty much crashed and burned everything for IE. Thanks, sometimes I just need an additional set of eyes looming over it :D

Answer (score 0):

To get LIs to align properly inline in most if not all browsers without the need for using floats try the below code example.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li>Text 1</li>
</ul>


ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    display: inline;
}
li a {
    /* Add any styling you want here for your list item links */
    display: inline-block;
}
```